# changing style with JS makes a hidden input field disappear?

Tags: javascript, css, hidden-field

im drawing a table with dates with a load of hidden fields

```
print   "<td";
{ $dm=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+".$i." days", strtotime($m)));
print " class=\"overflow\"  id=\"$a::$dm\" onclick=\"function1(this)\" "
print " >";
print  "<input type='hidden' id=\""."hidden:$a::$dm"."\"    name=\"hiddenfield\" value='123' >";
}   
print " </td>";
```

then i want to click on the cell and add a value to the hidden element,and change the color of adjacent cells

but when the javascript changes style, the hidden element  isnt accessible and the length of the array decrements by one each time

i can put the hidden  input fields outside the table , but can i fix this ?

Javascript ........

```
>    days=5;
>     for (i=(c+1); i<(c+days);i++)
>     {
>     myTable.rows[r].cells[i].innerHTML = '';
>     j=myTable.rows[r].cells[i].id;//alert(i +" "+j) 
>     document.getElementById(j).style.borderRightStyle = "none";
>     document.getElementById(j).style.borderLeftStyle = "none";
>     document.getElementById(j).className = 'active'; 
>     ajj='hidden::'+j;alert(ajj);
>     //alert(document.getElementById(ajj).value)
>     alert(document.getElementsByName("hiddenfield").length);
>     }
```

i get a console message  when i try to inspect that element
alert(document.getElementById(ajj).value) is null

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line

```
myTable.rows[r].cells[i].innerHTML = '';
```

You are removing everything between your `<td>` tags, which includes the input field. Changing the style has nothing to do with it.